# How do I add an input to rows until a new input exists?

Tags: ms-access

[image: This is what my MS Access data looks like]

How do I change 12 and 13 to fill in with 'ARCH' and 14 to 36 to fill in with 'ENVD'?  This goes on with over 4000 subjects, and 10000 rows changing at random times.  How can I tell ms access to write some letters until it sees a new set of letter, then write those until it sees a new set?

Comment: You're going to have to be clearer. I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: Have you imported this data from Excel? I hope you allowed MS Access to add a primary key or you are likely to end up with miss-assigned rows. A relational database does not have an order, other than that assigned by a sort, so do not be surprised if you end up with all subjects at the top of the table.

Answer (score 1):

IF you have an autonumber field, it can be done simpler. for now I assume you don't have an AutoNumber field and have done it with a reading one record at a time.

**You have to change the tblname to your actual table name on line 8th**

```
Sub test()
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql As String
Dim val As String

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

sql = "SELECT * FROM tblname"
rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

With rs
    If Not .EOF Then
        val = !field3
        .MoveNext
        Do
            If !field3 = "" Then
                !field3 = val
                .Update
            Else
                val = !field3
            End If

            .MoveNext
        Loop Until .EOF

    End If

End With
```

End Sub